Laravel 6 Task Scheduler Issue: Commands Not Executing
I'm encountering an issue with Laravel 6's task scheduler, where scheduled commands are not running as expected.
I want to automate two methods in two different classes using Laravel's task scheduler. To achieve this, I've created two files in the app/Commands folder, each containing a $signature variable and a handle() method.
Here's an example of the handle() method in one of the command files (AutoCommand.php):
public function handle()
{
    $autoController = new AutoController();
    $autoController->autoMethod();
    $this->info('The task is completed');
}

And here's my Kernel.php file where I define the schedule:
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // This command should run every 3 hours
    $schedule->command('first:command')->cron('0 */3 * * *');
    // This command should run daily at midnight
    $schedule->command('second:command')->daily(); 
}

When I execute php artisan schedule:run, I receive the following error message:

No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Laravel Version: 6.20.34
PHP Version: 7.4.33 (cli)
I've tried adjusting the schedule options per the Laravel documentation, but the issue persists.
Changing the schedule to run every minute (->everyMinute()) works fine, but I specifically need one command to run every 3 hours and the other one daily.
I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue with Laravel's task scheduler.

Is your question specifically about PHP 7.4 features or is that just the version of PHP you happen to be using?

The current project I am working is in PHP 7.4 version.

Be sure that your custom commands are properly registered in the app/Console/Kernel.php file's commands array.

schedule:run designed to be launched automatically, only if it launched at right timing with scheduled commands. To achieve that,you should create one single record in your cron. Execute thecrontab -e  and enter code like
* * * * * cd /path/to/your/project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

then save it,and cron will automatically refresh,without any reloads
I guess it works like that because of schedule:run compares cron rule at the moment of execution with current time,and if it matches,it will run,else it will return

No scheduled commands are ready to run

But since you running command manually, you have no opportunity to getting into timings perfetctly,so it fails
PS: you also could try to run php artisan schedule:work if you dont want to deal with cron

Thansk for your response.
I have added the crontab -e already. And waited for 1 day as well if it could run for daily bases. But didn't get any result.
Also with the schedule:work command I am getting this
Command "schedule:work" is not defined.
Did you mean one of these?
queue:work
schedule:run
will try with single record in the cron and check the result.
Thanks

oh seems like schedule:work is not available in ver 6,it was introduced only at version 8, my bad
also,did you checked your /storage/logs files? when you scheduling your taks,you will get output of scheduled commands only in files there

Yes, I am checking the output there but there is no result.
When I changed in the schedule function to { ->everyMinute() }  then it stated giving logs in the laravel.log file but with my desired timing (every 3 hours and daily) it is not working.
